# Problems with my thermostat

Tags: thermostat, electric-heat

My thermostat will turn on the baseboard electric heater but will keep running till you turn it all the way off.

Comment: Sounds like a bad themostat , they cost like $15.  Wiring them up involves touching mains voltage, so you'll want skill at that, or help.

Answer (score 1):

Harper is right.  Also, old line-voltage thermostats crepe upward eventually never turning the heat off at all.  If you elect to change it yourself. Turn the breaker off first.  Swap it out wire for wire.  Use new properly sized, quality wire nuts and crank them down tight. P.